# ¿Cómo uso el carácter '&' en una llamada a cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

Estoy haciendo una llamada con cURL que debe contener un ampersand &:

```
curl http://midominio.cat?par1=foo&par2=bar
```

El problema es que `&` es un carácter especial para Bash, por lo que no se pasa correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo corregirlo? Escapar con `\&` no me soluciona el problema.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13339469/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa comillas alrededor de la URL:

```
curl "http://midominio.cat?par1=foo&par2=bar"
```

De este modo sí podrás pasar el ampersand tranquilamente. Si vas a usar alguna variable, usa comillas dobles para que `$variable` se expanda. Si no es el caso y quieres que el contenido sea literalmente lo que escribas, usa comillas simples.